# MS Access select query to compare two table

Tags: ms-access

I am first time using MS access.

I have created two tables in a MS Access database. Table 1 has six columns, hundred rows and table 2 has two columns, five rows.

all the 3 columns in table 2 are also present in table 1.

now I want to retrieve rows from table 1 which are matching in table 2.

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

You need a straightforward join query to do this like so:

SELECT * 
FROM first_table a, second_table b
WHERE a.column1 = b.column1 AND a.column2 = b.column2

etc

Join all three columns that must match between the two tables and the result will be only records that match all columns.

Comment: how do I import a word document as a template for report in MS access?

Comment: Post this as a new question. Also click the check mark when you are happy with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Choose one of your columns which is present in both tables and has unique values (let's call it ID in this example). Then, open the SQL view and run the following query:

```
SELECT a.* FROM Table1 a JOIN Table2 b ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: Thnks but I have to match all the 3 columns from table 2 with table 1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch only the common rows, use inner join

For getting the modified/inserted rows in NewTable use right join

*Common Rows*

select a.* from OldTable a inner join NewTable b ON a.column1 = b.column2 and a.column2 = b.column3 and a.coulmn3 = b.column3

*ModifiedRows*

select b.column1, b.column2,b.column3 from OldTable a right join NewTable b ON a.column1 = b.column2 and a.column2 = b.column3 and a.coulmn3 = b.column3 Where a.column1 is null or a.column2 is null or a.column3 is null

```
select b.column1, b.column2,b.column3 from OldTable a right join NewTable b ON a.column1 = b.column2 and a.column2 = b.column3 and a.coulmn3 = b.column3 Where a.column1 is null or a.column2 is null or a.column3 is null
```